# Get a field placed in the header of a grid column. Extjs 6

Tags: filter, grid, remote-server, extjs6

I'm working on a grid with a remote filter. So, i set a field in a grid column header.

My question is,

How can i get the field value without field-id ??

See the example below

[image]

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to bind the value config of your textfield (the textfield in your items of the column header) to an attribute in a view model.

Something like :

```
    var vm = Ext.create('Ext.app.ViewModel', {

    data: [{
        test : ''
    }],

    alias: 'viewmodel.myviewmodel', 

    stores: {
        simpsonsStore: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data:[
                {'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-111-1224"},
                {'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1234"},
                {'name': 'Homer', "email":"homer@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1244"},
                {'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"}
            ]
        })
    }
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    viewModel: vm,
    layout: 'hbox',

    items:[{
        xtype: 'button',
        bind: {
            text: '{test}'
        }
    },{
        xtype: 'grid',
        flex: 1,
        bind: '{simpsonsStore}',
        columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                bind: {
                    value: '{test}'
                }
            }]
        }, {
            text: 'Email',
            dataIndex: 'email',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            text: 'Phone',
            dataIndex: 'phone'
        }]
    }]
});
```

PS : here is the fiddle ;) https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15j6 you can type in your header filed, the button text will updated automatically :)